# Centered CSS flexbox - Firefox bug when position absolute is used?

Tags: css, firefox, css-position, flexbox

I have this problem when absolute position is used with a centered flexbox item. It does not work in Firefox.

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4qDUp/).

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>Center me!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
    width:350px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid black;

    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;

    /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    display:inline-flex;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;

    /* Safari and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;

    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    box-pack:center;
    box-align:center;
}
```

Any idea how can I fix this, as I need to use absolute position in the div?

Comment: These properties are from the 2009 spec and are being phased out in favor of the current spec.  If you're using these properties because you need to support older/mobile browsers, make sure you're also providing their modern counterparts.  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/727c9d558b374d27c5b6

Comment: There's an open bug in the Gecko rendering engine: [Bug 579776](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579776). `position:absolute` changes the display property from `display:-moz-box` to `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by putting an extra div inside my absolutely positioned element, giving it display flexbox and then 100% height and width.

```
<div class='container'>
<div>Centered Text here</div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle with my implementation: [My Solution (http://jsfiddle.net/pmvjb/)](http://jsfiddle.net/pmvjb/)